# Wix deployment: WinForms Report

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wix

I'm trying to deploy a winforms application using WIX to create the .exe.
I has able to create the .exe and install my application.
But I could not print the report - there is no preview of the report, the app just prints my report. When I try I get the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

in the following line:

```
LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
```

When a I run my application on VS2013 it works fine, but the deployed application does not work (same machine).

I have a Bundle.wxs:

```
<PackageGroup Id="ReportViewer">
  <MsiPackage Id="ReportViewer"
              SourceFile="Files\ReportViewer.msi"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              InstallCondition="VersionNT >= v5.1 AND NOT ReportViewer10Install = 1"/>
</PackageGroup>
```

and a Product.wxs​

```
<Component Guid="xxx">
    <File Source="$(var.Forms.TargetDir)\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
<Component Guid="xxx">
    <File Source="$(var.Forms.TargetDir)\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
<Component Guid="xxx">
    <File Source="$(var.Forms.TargetDir)\Reports\MyReport.rdlc" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

The Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll are mark as true for "Copy local".

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was not the LocalReport that was null.
The problem was with the report path, it was null. So I fix it and it runs ok now.

I guess there is no need to add this lines also:

```
<Component Guid="xxx">
<File Source="$(var.Forms.TargetDir)\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
<Component Guid="xxx">
<File Source="$(var.Forms.TargetDir)\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```